# Classes, Inheritence and virtual functions

Tags: c++

```
class Musician {
public: virtual void play() { std::cout << "Play an instrument"; }
 };

class Guitarist : public Musician {
public: void play() { std::cout << "Play a guitar"<<endl; }
};

int main(){
Musician armstrong;
Guitarist steve;
Musician* m = &armstrong;
m->play();
m = &steve; //type of (m)=Musician type of (*m) = Guitarist???
}
```

Why is the type of (*m) = Guitarist? And why if I remove virtual keyword in function of Musician class then type of (*m) = Musician?

```
class Musician {
public: void play() { std::cout << "Play an instrument"; } //this makes type of(*m) = Musician
 };
```

If I add `armstrong = static_cast<Musician>(steve);` at the end it donot give error but cause no change (of addr and type) to armstrong. What is the meaning of that line?
Whereas `steve = static_cast<Guitarist>(armstrong);` gives error :

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'Guitarist::Guitarist(Musician&)'
   27 | steve=static_cast<Guitarist>(armstrong);
      |                                       ^
```

Comment: You can't cast a non-pointer. What would that even mean? Going up the chain is fine, but recasting to a child class makes no sense either. The point of polymorphism in C++ is to avoid casting whenever possible. Let the virtual function handler take care of things for you.

Comment: `then type of` how do you check type?

Comment: **static** type of `m` is `Musician*`, its **dynamic** type depends of its value (`&amstrong` or `&steve`). `virtual` methods use dynamic type, whereas regular methods use static type.

Comment: @KamilCuk using #include<typeinfo>

Comment: You are outputting variable `b`: `std::cout << "Play a guitar"<<b<<endl;` Where is `b` defined?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have defined it earlier for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to do this before while I was learning here's I had come with a solution you can replace A with Musician and B with Guitarist.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  void Same(){
      std::cout << "From A" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual A& operator= (const A& a) {
    assign(a);
    return *this;
  }

protected:
  void assign(const A& a) {
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void Same(){
      std::cout << "From B" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual B& operator= (const A& a) {
    if (const B* b = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&a))
      assign(*b);
    return *this;
  }

protected:
  void assign(const B& b) {
    A::assign(b); 
  }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    B b;
    a.Same();
    a = b;
    a.Same();
    return 0;
}
```